# Is it correct that $\text{Cov}(X,Y) = \text{E}((X-\text{E}(X))Y)$?

Tags: probability

We have that $\text{Cov}(X,Y) = \text{E}\left( (X-\mu_x)(Y-\mu_y)\right) = \text{E}\left(XY -\mu_yX - \mu_xY + \mu_x\mu_y  \right) = E(XY) - \mu_y\mu_x - \mu_x\mu_y + \mu_x\mu_y = E(XY) - \mu_x\mu_y$.

We also have that $\text{E}\left( (X-\mu_x)Y\right) = \text{E}\left(XY - \mu_xY \right) = \text{E}(XY) - \mu_x\text{E}(Y) = \text{E}(XY) -\mu_x\mu_y = \text{Cov}(X,Y)$

I have never seen $\text{E}\left( (X-\mu_x)Y\right)$ being used to compute or define the covariance of $X$ and $Y$, but it is correct, or?

Comment: I haven't seen such formula either, but seems to be correct

Comment: The covariance doesn't change if you shift one or both of $X,Y$ by any constant.

Comment: @Byron: So except for $\text{E}\left( (X-\mu_x)(Y-\mu_y)\right) = \text{E}\left( (X-\mu_x)Y\right)$, we could also shift $X$ by $\mu_x$ to get $\text{Cov}(X,Y) = E(XY)$? Something seems wrong there.

Comment: @TMM : One could so shift $X$ but not $Y$ and it would be correct, but when _both_ are shifted then it's wrong.  This is a very well known identity.

Comment: @TMM $\mathbb{E}((X-\mu_X)Y)$ is the covariance of $X-\mu_X$ and $Y$ but $\mathbb{E}(XY)$ is not the covariance of $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: Shift both of them? Sure about that? If they are shifted by a and b, wouldn't the corresponding covariance increase by the amount ab?

Comment: @ByronSchmuland : The covariance doesn't change if you shift one or both.  But $\mathbb E((X-\mu_x)(Y-\mu_Y))$ does change if you shift both, but not if you shift only one.  As soon as you shift $Y-\mu_Y$ to anything whose expected value is not $0$, then shifting $X-\mu_X$ will change the value of the whole expression.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting; I wasn't aware of this fact, but I don't see any errors in your derivation. (it's not a concept I've ever dealt much with)

At first glance, it looks like the usual definition has pedagogical advantages, making obvious two key properties:

- Covariance is symmetric: Cov(X,Y) = Cov(Y,X)
- Covariance depends only on how much the random variables differ from their means

As for computation, I think the alternative you suggest only has niche uses: I imagine that for nearly every purpose, at least one of $E((X - \mu_x)(Y - \mu_y))$ or $E(XY) - \mu_x \mu_y$ is more computationally convenient than $E((X - \mu_x) Y)$: the former due to smaller numbers and better numerical stability, and the latter due to ease of tabulation and simpler formulas.

Comment: Yes, I agree with what you said. I was actually given E((X-E(X))Y) and then it said that it was equal to Cov(X,Y) so I had to convince myself, and the astonishment that followed made me post it here.

Comment: Interesting to see all these expressions of surprise, including one from someone with a 22k reputation, for such a widely known identity.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Is it well known because it's so ugly you can't forget it?

Comment: @Lucas : More likely because it's in every introductory textbook.

Comment: @Michael: As I mentioned, I've had little reason to deal with covariance, so I remember little more than knowing where to start looking if I ever encounter a problem that isn't easy enough to work out from first principles. I *have* done numerical calculation, though, so I'm rather surprised by your suggestion that $E((X-\mu_x)Y)$ is good for efficient calculation -- at first glance it would seem the only situation would be in the specific situation where you've done the work to compute $\mu_x$ but not  $\mu_y$ (and you do not need the better numerical stability of $E((X-\mu_x)(Y-\mu_y))$).

Answer (score 1):

It is correct and it is fairly frequently seen in statistics textbooks.  In the case of a finite sample, one sees it written as
$$
\frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\bar x)y_i = \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n x_i (y_i-\bar y) = \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\bar x)(y_i - \bar y).
$$
Or sometimes with Bessel's correction, so that $n-1$ appears instead of $n$.  It can be somewhat more computationally efficient to use one of the first two forms above than the third one.

Comment: Alright. I have seen it in the context of sample covariance, but it didn't come to mind when I was working with the expectation operator. For some reason it appeared conceptually different to me.